# C/C++ struct packing not working

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof, packing

I'm trying to pack a struct, using g++ on <strike>64-bit</strike> 32-bit windows.

```
struct Foo
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
} __attribute__((packed));


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "sizeof(Foo):" << sizeof(Foo);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs 8. Other things I've tried:

```
{ uint8_t a; } // Gives 1, correct.
{ uint8_t a; float b; } // Gives 8, expected 5.
{ uint8_t a; uint16_t b; } // Gives 4, expected 3.
{ uint16_t a; uint8_t b; uint8_t c; } // Gives 4, correct.
```

So it seems like the struct is packed, but `sizeof` is rounded up in some cases? (Actually after having written this question I think I can answer it, but I'll post it anyway for posterity.)

Edit: Actually I have no idea. I thought `aligned(1)` would fix it but it doesn't.

Comment: If you can answer it, go ahead.

Comment: @Timmmm If you are coding in c use `#pragma pack(1)`.

Comment: If you want them smaller try putting smaller types last in the struct.

Comment: If this is a G++-specific feature, the question should be tagged as such.

Comment: I'm using C++, and it's specific to g++ and Clang. You can add the tags if you want.

Comment: everything as it should if packing by 4 bytes, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah actually my answer didn't work. I thought `aligned(1)` had fixed it but it didn't actually change the results.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with gcc or clang, neither in C nor in C++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ff9e0377db2b178

Comment: Which version of g++ do you use? I got the expected sizes with g++ 4.6.2 on my 64-bits Windows.

Comment: I compiled your code on my machine and it output 8. Much be architecture dependent. This is my g++ version: `g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.2` Oh and actually I just realised I'm on a *32-bit* Windows 7 machine. Still that shouldn't make a difference should it?

Comment: You're using MinGW-W64 on 32-bit windows?

Comment: "Built by [MinGW-W64 project](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found it is [a bug in g++](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/275/).

> The general issue is that the **attribute** ((__packed)) applies only
>   to last field of struct. This is the cause for the size of 9. Trick is
>   here '#pragma pack(1)'. By it you get expected sizes. The issue is
>   that this field-alignment gets applied even for struct/union's marked
>   to be packed (or via -fpack-struct option).

Well there seems to be some doubt of that explanation, but the solution works - use `#pragma pack(1)` instead like this:

```
#pragma pack(1)

struct Foo
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
};

#pragma pack()
```

The second `#pragma` resets the pack value.

Comment: This is a bug since (apparently) g++ 4.7 with MinGW. I had correct sizes with g++ 4.6.2, I've just upgraded to 4.8.1 and now I get the wrong sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Should be 5 when packed, works for me on

> Linux version 3.13.0-32-generic (buildd@kissel) (gcc version 4.8.2
>   (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014

and

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
unsigned char a;
unsigned int b;
} __attribute__((packed));


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
cout << "sizeof(Foo):" << sizeof(Foo);
return 0;
}
```

Success 
comments (0)
stdin
copy

Standard input is empty

stdout
copy

sizeof(Foo):5

[Compiled on Ideone](http://ideone.com/KUsSw8)