# Union fails to decode byte array

Tags: c

The following code fails to decode the latitude and longitude.
The output is: `132, 1, 1645780273, 77276230, 0, -0.000000, 0.000000`, doing a wrong conversion on the last 2 values latitude & longitude.
If I remove the first 4 values and delete `uint32_t identifiers;` from the struct i get the correct result `132, 1, 1645780273, 77276230, 0, 59.877871, 10.465200`

Any help in understanding this behavior ist very appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    union  {
        unsigned char bytes[36];
        struct{
            uint32_t identifier;
            uint16_t telegram_size;
            uint16_t telegram_version;
            uint32_t seconds;
            uint32_t nanoseconds;
            uint32_t stat;
            double latitude;
            double longitude;
      }unpack;
    }telegram;

    unsigned char values[] = {0x23, 0x4B, 0x4D, 0x42, 0x84, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x31, 0x9d, 0x18, 0x62, 0x46, 0x24, 0x9b, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x9d, 0x3e, 0x2c, 0x11, 0x5e, 0xf0, 0x4d, 0x40, 0xCA, 0x32, 0xC4, 0xB1, 0x2E, 0xEE, 0x24, 0x40};
    memcpy(telegram.bytes, values, 36);

    for (int i=0;i<36;i++){
        printf("%02X ", telegram.bytes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%u, %u, %u, %u, %u, %f, %f\n", telegram.unpack.telegram_size, telegram.unpack.telegram_version, telegram.unpack.seconds, telegram.unpack.nanoseconds, telegram.unpack.stat, telegram.unpack.latitude, telegram.unpack.longitude);
    return 0;
}
```

Update: As far as I understood from the comments below the struct looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Try to print `sizeof(telegram)` or `sizeof(telegram.unpack)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with struct padding.

Generally speaking, members of a struct start at an offset which is a multiple of that member's size for alignment purposes.  Because of this, there are 4 padding bytes between the `stat` and `latitude` members so that the latter can reside at an offset that is a multiple of 8.  That means the struct is 4 bytes larger than you think it is.

If you're able to, you should rearrange the members so that they align at a natural offset so that there is no padding between the members (although there may still be padding at the end).

If that's not an option, you can pack the struct using a compiler-specific attribute.  If you're using gcc, you would do the following:

```
    struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
        uint32_t identifier;
        uint16_t telegram_size;
        uint16_t telegram_version;
        uint32_t seconds;
        uint32_t nanoseconds;
        uint32_t stat;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
  }unpack;
```

Note also that on some architectures, an unaligned read or write can cause a crash.

Comment: gcc has a bug which still exists at least in MinGW, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887459/c-c-struct-packing-not-working. It may be necessary to use `#pragma pack...` instead of the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, for that quick answer. Just for some more clarification. That padding ist already happening when i do the memcpy because the compiler 'knows' the there ist that odd structure in the union?

Comment: @PaulBoettinger The struct has the padding at the point it is defined, so it is 40 bytes in size.  Then the `memcpy` writes to the first 36 of those 40 bytes.

Comment: Still many questions left.
If doing so, why do latitude and longitude not point to the correct memory adress?
Why do i get correct values for the 4 variables before latitude and
why do lat and long point to somewhere, returning 0?

Comment: @PaulBoettinger Because the padding starts right before `latitude`.  That makes that field and any others following it end up in the wrong place.

Comment: @dbush got that one, because the 8-byte schema breaks before the doubles.
Can anybody please giv me some more insights how the memory is adressed:
Why does everything work fine if I iterate over the byte array (not seeing the padding at all)? In the struct the compiler adds padding, but why does it not get der memory of the struct variables addressed right?

Comment: @PaulBoettinger Not sure what you mean by "why does it not get der memory of the struct variables addressed right".  The struct is 40 bytes wide with the padding, with the 4 extra bytes being between `stat` and `latitude`.  When you copy your 36 bytes onto that, the first 20 bytes end up where you expect.  Then the next 4 bytes, which you intend to be part of `latitude`, get copied to the padding bytes.  Then the next 4 bytes, which should be the 4 low bytes of `latitude`, get put in the 4 high bytes of `latitude`...

Comment: @PaulBoettinger  Then the next 4 bytes, which should be the 4 high bytes of `longitude`, end up in the 4 low bytes of `latitude`.  Then the next 4 bytes, which should be the 4 low bytes of `longitude`, end up in the 4 high bytes of `longitude`.  The 4 low bytes of  `longitude` are then left unchanged.

Comment: @dbush Thanks for your patience. I've added a picture to the original question with the layout of the struct as far as i understood it.
What confuses me, probably because i don't have a good understanding how the stuff is arranged in memory, are two things:
1. If I iterate over the telegram.bytes array everything's fine, i don't see the padding, which I would expect to be seen at telegram.bytes[20...23]
2. If i print latitude i get 0 as a result which means it's not the 8 bytes starting at position 20 nor 24.

Comment: @PaulBoettinger The bytes array doesn't have any padding since it's just an array of bytes.  The picture you've made is accurate, and because of the union the `bytes` array overlays the first 36 bytes of the struct.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that the structure is laid out with all members contiguous.  That is not a safe assumption.  Implementations are free to insert arbitrary padding into structure layouts between members and after the last member.  In practice, they will do so in a manner that allows them to ensure that all members can be properly aligned in memory.

In your particular case, your 8-byte `doubles` want to be aligned on 8-byte boundaries.  Your implementation is ensuring that they can be by putting them at offsets from the beginning of the structure that are multiples of 8 bytes.  That involves inserting four bytes of otherwise unused padding between `stat` and `latitude`, which your initialization does not account for.  The overall structure will also have an 8-byte alignment requirement, and its total size will be a multiple of 8 bytes.

Removing the four-byte initial member allows the two `double`s to be aligned without any padding, which is why that variation on your program worked as you expected.