# Is there a compile flag in Clang to force the compiler to prevent struct padding in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, clang

The attributes for packing must be annotated for every struct declaration. I am wondering whether there exists a compiler flag to automatically pack all structs?

Tried looking through the clang documentation as well as define options but nothing seems to fit

Comment: You might want to give some reasons *why* you want all structures be packed, as you will experience some performance penalty when doing that.

Answer (score 3):

Try `-fpack-struct`. From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fpack-struct), however the flag is also available in Clang:

> `-fpack-struct[=n]`
>
> Without a value specified, pack all structure members together without holes. When a value is specified (which must be a small power of two), pack structure members according to this value, representing the maximum alignment (that is, objects with default alignment requirements larger than this are output potentially unaligned at the next fitting location.
>
> **Warning:** the `-fpack-struct` switch causes GCC to generate code that is not binary compatible with code generated without that switch. Additionally, it makes the code suboptimal. Use it to conform to a non-default application binary interface.

Answer (score 1):

Note also that Clang (as GCC) does support the MSVC extension of `#pragma pack` to enable selective packing on long runs of code.

You can then surround your structures definitions with

```
#pragma pack(push,1)

struct One {
  ...
};
...
struct Nth {
  ...
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

and everything in between will be byte-packed (requesting 1-byte alignment).

This is usually highly desirable, as you can restrict the packing to the storage definitions you absolutely need, while all the rest of the code will follow the general rules - not breaking compatibility with other sources, and not missing the data access optimization that the compiler would like to enforce.

See [Clang manual](https://releases.llvm.org/3.4/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#microsoft-extensions) and [MSVC reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-170)

Comment: It also supports gcc `__attribute__((packed))` which might be preferred.  The behaviour of a compiler presented with an unrecognised pragma directive is to ignore it, whereas an unrecognised compiler extension would fail to compile (which is a good thing if packed is truly necessary).

Comment: @Clifford Unfortunately, GCC had (has?) a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887459/c-c-struct-packing-not-working) in the implementation of `__attribute__((packed))`. I discovered this the hard way and ended up using the pragma-notation instead. It should be possible to make a `static_assert` to flag if the compiler does not pack as expected (e.g. on a test struct type made only for that purpose).

Comment: @LuC When I use structure packing it is rarely (maybe never) with the purpose of saving storage, but to define structures for communication or storage.

Comment: @Clifford `#pragma pack` is well recognized by MSVC, GCC, and Clang (the latter in OP), then I presume it to fit the purpose. If I had to speak about standards, well, ISO just defines padding of elements **unspecified**, then I should say that any means to force it is **non-portable**. However, in real world we just need it all the time. The preference for `__attribute__((packed))` can be fine, if you just don't mind portability to anything other than GCC/Clang. The annoying part is that it has to be repeated for each struct

Comment: @nielsen I think that the description of an externally forced byte-level allocation (communication protocol, hardware peripheral) is the most common use. However, working with very resource-constrained embedded systems I often had to employ packing (e.g. fitting more complex data in an EEPROM). On medium to large systems has little use, unless start allocating millions of elements of a struct

Comment: Yes, I don't disagree, just presenting it as an option.  Support in gcc is somewhat "recent" it was not always thus, and gcc documentation previously actively discouraged `pragma`s. The need to apply it individually to each struct is better perhaps than needlessly applying it to everything without consideration of the consequences as warned if in the `-fpack-struct` documentation.  Packing _should_ be used selectively, and cumbersome syntax makes that more likely perhaps.

Comment: @Clifford Well, I remember `#pragma pack` support for some time now, then I just checked its manuals: it's been there since GCC 4.0, from April 2005. After 18 years it has the **legal age**, at least here in my country :^)

Comment: @LuC : I have been a s/w developer professionally since 1989 - 2005 seems like yesterday.  And at that time in embedded systems in which I work, gcc versions tended to lag behind that used in Linux for example.

Comment: @Clifford same here :D